# 0x80070643 error while installing Python 3.6

Tags: python, installation

I'm actually using Python for an audio steganography project but I have some troubles.
I searched this error code on the forum, but I found things about SQL installations and not Python.

I'm trying to re-install Python 3.6.5 after an uninstall, because of a bug with pip.

I installed Python 2.7, Python 3.6.5, Python with VS 2017, before uninstall it because it wasn't working.

However, when I'm runing the installer as an administrator, hit "customize installation", tick everything excpet "balblalblabal (this requires VS 2015 or later)", and click on "install", it tells me that :
[image: capture 1] [image: capture 2].

I realy need Python to work and I'm now stuck ...

If anybody here could help me, it would be nice !
Thanks all,
maleik.

PS : I have the log for you :*

[The log link](http://dl.free.fr/oI5yf2s2s)

Comment: Uh oh, I missed clicked and remove my "Hi there"
So I tell you this now : "Hi there !"

Comment: no, "Hi there" is considered as noise and is automatically removed from questions

Comment: can you try to disable windows defender while you're installing?

Comment: I do not use Windows Defender but I use ESET as antivirus software. I disabled it for 10 minutes, let's try.
One thing else : un bonjour de Laval ^^

Comment: Don't work .. :/

Comment: not possible that you cannot install python. Try to deinstall it, then try installing the 64 bit version or 3.7 version; Try something different here in Laval.

Comment: I've already uninstalled it, in the control Pannel.

Ok, I just tried somthing that half-solves my problem : I can install it in "This user only" mode (that I done) but I'm unable to do it in "All users"mode.
I can use Python, but it doest not tells me why there is still a 3.6 version installed.

Comment: I got this error today and I can confirm that, disabling Windows Defender, installing a higher version then uninstalling it and installing the broken version, and CCleaner's registry wipe all do not fix this issue. However, I have yet to try doing all of this in a French town as I'm sure @Jean-FrançoisFabre was suggesting. I got it working the same as OP by just doing the plain user install, but I was unable to put it at `C:\\Pythonxy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the log file which you have attached. Try cleaning the registry with CC cleaner and give it a try. If it still doesn't work, try installing python with web installer [Python Web Installed 3.6.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/).

```
[3DA0:2968][2018-12-05T20:46:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[3DA0:2968][2018-12-05T20:46:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2610:03A4][2018-12-05T20:46:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[2610:03A4][2018-12-05T20:46:18]i319: Applied execute package: core_AllUsers, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[2610:03A4][2018-12-05T20:46:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for comming to help me !
I launched CCleaner, and launched the web install, but it's still the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I installed python from **Microsoft store** after facing this problem and it magically got installed without any error as it may have directly been installed. I don't know but try if it eorks for you too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the installation as a local administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing Python version 3.9 for the first time on my Windows 10, as this same problem happens to many users trying to install Python, the best solution I accidentally, just like [@MANAN AGGARWAL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13488864/manan-aggarwal) discovered trying to check if I already had a version of Python installed on my computer by the DOS Command Prompt, was:

Open the DOS Command Prompt (cmd) and dictate "python": if a screen shows you a version, it's clearly not the first time you've installed Python, so if you want to upgrade you should try: [https: / /www.delftstack.com/en/howto/python/how-to-update-python/](http://https:%20/%20/www.delftstack.com/en/howto/python/how-to-update-python/) But if you've never installed any version of Python, the solution lies in updating your operating system to the latest version through Windows Update, and open the command prompt and type Python, or go directly to the Microsoft Store and search for Python followed by its latest version. It works without error.
** If by chance it does not automatically install on your PC after downloading, click "install on my devices" and select your computer name.

Why can't I install Python directly from the website file? Please note that when trying to install any software/applications from outside Microsoft's trusted locations, there are high chances of user settings interfering with the installation. When coming, for example, from the Microsoft Store, a chance of success is much greater, even without having problems related to User Permission Settings.

Another important thing to point out here is that installing a lot of software from outside Microsoft's trusted platforms can cause you to change some user permissions which can have positive effects with some software and negative effects with others, even with security your own system if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you. Installing it via the Microsoft Store worked surprisingly well and resolved all the issues. Never did figure out why I couldn't install it via the Python website, but hey as long as it works.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple , Try Lower Version Like 'Python 3.6' but Download web install.
install it , then install last python version.
your python will update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same/similar problem with installing Python 3.9.12 in a clean Windows 8.1 64-bit (VirtualBoxed test environment).

I thought the issue could have been fixed in a newer version of Python, but the freshest 3.10.10 fails with same issue.

The original log isn't available any longer, but luckily it is quoted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640223/536172), and the following line reveals the real problem:

```
Applied execute package: core_AllUsers, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
```

My log looks the same, and if you scroll the log up, you'll discover that `core_AllUsers` is a UCRT MSI-installer, which is downloaded from Python site (for 3.10.10 64-bit the link may look like https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.10/amd64/ucrt.msi).

If you download it manually (Python installer is smart enough to do a cleanup even if it fails, so you won't find this MSI in a local cache) and run, it will probably crash. And if it is your case, I have a simple solution - just **install update [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c) (Update for Universal C Runtime)** for your OS, which you can download from Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the similar issue. What the trick worked for me is I installed it for the individual user (as earlier installation was for the all users).
So earlier if one has installed it for the all users then install it for the specific user and vice versa.

I know this is not the resolution of the error faced. However, this approach will install Python which is the main motive to achieve.

Comment: please add more details to your answer

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue after installing a fresh Windows 8.1 on my PC.
I solved that by using the Python v3.9 web installation file which you can find [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

However, you can choose any other version that has a web installation file

Note: You need internet connection to use this method.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32477217)